# libslidemenu library is not working for android 4.3 version

Tags: android, performance

I'm using ActionShrelockBar & libslidemenu library.

The slide menu work's fine for 2.3 to 4.2.

But when i tried it in 4.3 latest version of android the slidemenu crashes .

I tried by adding support library but no go.

```
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.ClassCastException:      com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu.show(SlideMenu.java:317)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu.show(SlideMenu.java:260)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.hrh.lba.fragments.CategoryFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(CategoryFragment.java:326)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:127)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at  com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:603) 
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:78)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:205)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:171)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-26 02:04:14.400: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried with this patch .

And it's working great for 4.3 now .

[Patch](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu/commit/0fe72c09af6db5df07cd07c5f6de3b8fc65e8a1e#L1R307)

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the first string:

> com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.FrameLayout

Check source of SlideMenu.java at line 317

There must be some changes to SDK, so that you don't get expected class there.

Comment: How can i fix it any idea ..??

Comment: 4.3 was presented only couple of days ago and there are practically no compatible devices on market yet (OK, new Nexus 7). How do you expect to get an answer? And also - you are the only one who sees code, we have no telepathic powers.